# Query to get last posts from authors of blog

Tags: wp-query, users

Firstly I get user with role "author".

```
$author_args = array(
'role' => 'author'
);
$authors_list = get_users($author_args);
```

Nextly I reform array

```
$author_list = array();
foreach((array)$authors_list as $author) $author_list[] = $author->user_nicename;
```

And then finally query args

```
$author_posts_args = array(
        'author_name' => $author_list,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat'  => $colecti_id,
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
);
$author_posts_query = new WP_Query($author_posts_args);
```

Why it doesn't works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get author ids instead of author nicename to get posts for muliiple authors using [WP_Query();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$author_list = array();
foreach((array)$authors_list as $author) $author_list[] = $author->ID;

// make comma separated string from author ids array
$author_list = implode(',', $author_list)
```

and change wp query args

```
$author_posts_args = array(
    'author' => $author_list,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat'  => $colecti_id,
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
);
$author_posts_query = new WP_Query($author_posts_args);
```

Comment: Yep! It works. Thank you. I looked in the Codex and there were written about 'author' arg that it uses (int), so I thought that I can't use strings or arrays. Poor me.